# Printing values of listview in dart

Tags: string, flutter, dart, listview

I want that x which is outside the loop should print the value of x which is inside the loop instead of printing null.

Class App{

String? x;

for(m=0;m<1;m++){
if(length == 2) {

```
                     print("item: ${list[1] ?? ''}");

                     x = list[1];

        print("x : $x"); print(x); // prints x=some value; 

                               }
      else{

        x = '';

        print('no value');
      }
    }
```

print(x); // prints x=null;

}

Comment: Can you mention your actual problem statement ? As here if you want to print the value of x  you can print it inside. In actual problem statement do you want to update any view in  a loop.?

Comment: What you want to do with the images , give a complete statement

Comment: Actually I am having array named as photoslist which contains n images Now I want to store photoslist[2] in x. means .I want to store image in index 3 in x.And then I will use this x as object for uploading image to server.

Comment: void main() {
  String? x;
  List<String> list = ["image1", "image2", "image3"];

  for (int m = 0; m < list.length; m++) {
    if (m == 2) {
      print("item: ${list[1] ?? ''}");
      x = list[2];
      print("x : $x");
      print(x);
    } else {
      x = '';
      print('no value');
    }
  }
  print("Final Value ${x}");
}

Comment: Not sure if it fulfills your  requirement

Answer (score 0):

You tried to iterate through a list but restricted the loop to 1(`m < 1`). Try out the following code

````
  String? x;
  List<String> list = ["image1", "image2", "image3"];

  for (int m = 0; m < list.length; m++) {
    if (m == 2) {
      print("item: ${list[1] ?? ''}");
      x = list[2];
      print("x : $x");
      print(x);
    } else {
      x = '';
      print('no value');
    }
  }
  print("Final Value ${x}");
}```
````